# Pillow 2.0 refuses to work with zlib

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I've taken so many approaches to trying to get this to work, my head is spinning.

I have Pillow installed on my Lubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) with Python 3.3.1. Any time I try to open a PNG image, it raises `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'zip_decoder'` followed by `OSError: decoder zip not available`. I've manually compiled zlib and it lives in `/usr/local/zlib/lib/libz.so`. There's a soft link at `/usr/lib/libz.so` pointing to it as well. I also have the `zlib1g` package installed through Synaptic.

I've tried installing Pillow through all of the following methods:

- Through Synaptic, with the python3-imaging package
- Through `pip3`
- Manual download/unpack/compile

On my attempts with `pip3` and manual compiles, I get this output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SETUP SUMMARY (Pillow 2.0.0 fork, originally based on PIL 1.1.7)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      2.0.0 (Pillow)
platform     linux 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32)
             [GCC 4.7.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
*** WEBP support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On manual installs, I go into `setup.py` and give `ZLIB_ROOT` a value of `'/usr/local/zlib/lib'`

Yet after all of this, Pillow just absolutely refuses to acknowledge the fact that zlib exists on my machine, and compiles without ZIP support.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing the "-devel" packages for zlib (and libjpeg, ... if you want to have support for JPEG and other file formats)? The devel packages contain the C headers that are needed to compile C code (such as the Pillow extension) that uses the libraries.

Comment: I don't freakin' believe it. Be right back, throwing myself out the nearest window...

Comment: I achieved the same result by installing zlib from source (on OS X 10.9) before pip installing pillow - thanks for the tip.